# R script that should plot xts class data to a png file doesn't produce a png file

Tags: r, plot, png, xts

> I had a working script that used a loop to produce many png file plots of xts class data. Now the script throws an error and if I comment out the line throwing the error  (a call to abline() ) then the script executes but without producing a png file. The issue seems to involve plotting xts class data and/or a loop or script.
>
> Searching on stackoverflow didn't provide a solution or reference to this issue. I've reproduced the issue in the following example. In practice, the script would use different filenames within the loop and non-trivial data.

```
# put following code in 'myscript.R' and execute using source('myscript.R',print.eval=TRUE) or  source('myscript.R')
# xts class data
data <- xts(seq(1:10),order.by=as.Date(seq(1:10)))

# a non xts version of same data
#data <- seq(1:10)

for(i in 1:1) {
filename <- 'myfile.png'
png(filename)
plot(data)
lines( (data-1),col='red')
abline(h=1)
dev.off()
}
# The call to abline in above script with xts class data gives error 'plot.new has not been called yet'
# If comment out the call to abline it completes but doesn't produce a png file
# script works fine with abline for non xts data
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `xts >= 0.10.1`, this saves to file what you want

```
for(i in 1:1) {
    filename <- 'myfile.png'
    png(filename)
    plot(data)
    print(lines( (data-1),col='red', on = 1))
    print(lines(xts(x = rep(1, NROW(data)), order.by = index(data)),col='green', on=  1)    )
    dev.off()
}
```

Use the `print` calls for the extra lines.  I'd also use `lines` for the horizonal line, instead of `abline`, as this is more consistent with plotting with xts.

Also your error can be avoided if you do `print(abline(h=1))`

Comment: Thank you! That works. At risk of asking another question, what changed to now require the use of 'print' (the script worked before without it) and how should I stay aware of such changes?

Comment: @tedthedog as a rule of thumb, when you generate plots in a loop, and add things to the plot, use print statements to make sure the extra things are printed (you need to do this in Shiny too, when making plots).   In *interactive* mode (outside a loop, sourcing line by line from the console etc), you don't need to use the print statements when making a plot, then adding new things (e.g. `ablines`) to the plot (which gets redrawn)